# passing lists to a function

Tags: python, loops

I need to perform a calculation that has 2 lists containing integers. I'm using a for loop for the same. I have no clue hoe do I change the lists during calculation. I have tried the below code. Could some one help me with a better approach.

```
def calculation(input1,input2):
    for i in range(2):
    val = input1

    cal1 = val[0] + 5
    cal2 = val[2] + 0.05
    print cal1,cal2

    i = i+1
    #now trying to assign 'input2' to 'val'
    input1 = "input"+str(i)




input1 = [10,20,30,40]
input2 = [1,2,3,4]  
calculation(input1,input2)

my output results should look like
>> 15,20.5
>>6,2.5
```

Comment: `input1 = "input"+str(i)` will only set a string 'input2' into the variable input1

Comment: yes, i understand that. How do I go further to convert the string as a list?

Comment: You dont even use the `input2` variable, so why have it?

Answer (score 2):

You're making things much harder than you need to. Just iterate over a list of the inputs:

```
def calculation(input1,input2):
    for val in (input1, input2):
      cal1 = val[0] + 5
      cal2 = val[2] + 0.05
      print cal1,cal2
```

Or, even simpler:

```
def calculation(*inputs):
    for val in inputs:
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass on a list of lists and then do a for loop on that list:

```
def calculation(ls):
    for list in ls:
        #your code here, list is input 1 and then input 2
```

Also, you added 0.05 instead of 0.5 and you have the wrong index, it should be val[1] not val[2] (in my code: list[1])

Comment: Happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution working for python2 and python3 :

```
def calculation(input_lists, n):
    for i in range(n):
        val = input_lists[i]
        cal1 = val[0] + 5
        cal2 = val[2] + 0.05
        print (cal1,cal2)

input1 = [10,20,30,40]
input2 = [1,2,3,4]  
calculation([input1,input2], 2)
```

Comment: Why bother with the `n` variable, when the `input_lists` variable knows it's length? You have possibility for error, if you change the length of `input_lists`, but not `n`. This is very `c` like, but at least there it's justified.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for for any number of inputs (including zero, which you may or may not want). The `*` operator in this case collects all the arguments into a list, which can be iterated over and the calculation run on each member.

```
def calculation(*inputs):
    for val in inputs:

        cal1 = val[0] + 5
        cal2 = val[2] + 0.05
        yield cal1, cal2


input1 = [10,20,30,40]
input2 = [1,2,3,4]

for c in calculation(input1,input2):
    print(c)
```

I also modified your function to yield the answer for each iteration, so the caller can decide what to do with it. In this case it just prints it, but it could use it in further calculations.

The result is

```
(15, 30.05)
(6, 3.05)
```

Which is not the same as your required result, but it is correct based on the indices you use in your original code. You should check your calculations again.